# Unable to run nosetests from Jenkins, error: ImportError: No module named

Tags: python, shell, jenkins, appium, nose

I want to run my Python test cases from Jenkins locally. I have a shell script which executes fine from terminal on my Mac:

```
$ cat script.sh 
#!/bin/bash
appium &
sleep 10s
cd /Users/<user>/eddie-qa/automation
nosetests -s --tc-file=/Users/<user>/eddie-qa/automation/mobile_automation/configs/local_config_android_galaxy_6_0.py --tc-format python mobile_automation.tests.login_logout.tests_login_logout:TestLogin.test_05_incorrect_username_login
```

But when I run it from Jenkins with the same script:

[image: Jenkins build config]

It returns error:
`ImportError: No module named mobile_automation.configs.devices`

My file `local_config_android_galaxy_6_0.py` starts with these lines:

`from mobile_automation.configs.devices import desired_caps
global config
config = {}`

and in the `devices.py` code starts with:

```
global desired_caps
```

I'm not sure why it fails.
If I execute script without `--tc-file=/Users/<user>/eddie-qa/automation/mobile_automation/configs/local_config_android_galaxy_6_0.py` then it works.

Project structure:

[image: Python structure]

If anyone has an idea please let me know.

Additional info:

- Nosetests: /usr/local/bin/nosetests
- Appium: v1.7.2
- Jenkins: running on http://localhost:8080/
- Mac: High Sierra, v.10.13.3

Comment: it could be your jenkins slave didnt set any of your .bash_profile settings
it may have a different $PATH env variable or other env variables...

Comment: Thanks @studioj . It was permission error, Jenkins didn't have access to Android/sdk and to some other folders. After adding permissions to needed deirectories it runned fine. Error I was receiving 'ImportError: No module named mobile_automation.configs.devices' was somewhat missleading for me.